# CakePHP 3: Retrieving deep associations

Tags: cakephp-3.0

My model has

`Conversations` - hasMany - `Messages`

`Conversations` - hasMany - `ConversationsRecipients`

`ConversationsRecipients` - belongTo - `Users` or `Applicants` (depending on the flag set by field `recipient_type`. If `recipient_type` is A then it means Applicants)

So when I try to retrieve conversations for a particular Applicant, I use the following code

```
$conversationsTable = TableRegistry::get('Conversations');
        $conversations = $conversationsTable->find()
            ->join([
                'ConversationsRecipients' => [
                    'table' => 'conversations_recipients',
                    'type' => 'inner',
                    'conditions' => ['recipient_id' => $id, 'recipient_type' => 'A']
                ]
            ])
            ->contain([
                'Messages.Users' => function ($q) {
                    return $q
                        ->select(['Users.username'])
                        ->contain(['UsersProfiles']);
                },
                'Messages.Applicants' => function($q) {
                    return $q
                        ->select(['Applicants.firstname', 'Applicants.lastname']);
                }
            ])
            ->all();
        return $conversations;
```

This works fine - except for one part - but it doesn't retrieve the deeply contained model - UsersProfiles. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return $q
    ->select(['Users.username'])
    ->autoFields(true)
    ->contain(['UsersProfiles']);
```

When you include a select in your query, that's *all* that Cake will include, unless you include the autoFields call.